# pointer getting reference to a return of a function

Tags: c++

Imagine we have a scope where a variable is defined and a pointer with larger scope gets this variable's reference. What happens when we leave the scope knowing that the pointer is defined in the outer scope, a class member for example.

```
   {
       int a = 6;
       pointa = &a; //defined out of this scope
   }
   //what happens here, pointa is still defined in this scope
```

EDIT: My question was concerning a more specific case which I cannot find an answer to (it feels like the answer lies within the dangling pointer explanation though).

Suppose foo() is a function that returns a double.
I tried this:

```
    int* p;
    p = &foo();
```

But then p becomes empty.
Can you please explain how this relates to a dangling pointer?

Comment: UB͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: Try it. See what happens :)

Comment: You could answer this question with a tiny amount of basic knowledge of the language and/or a tiny amount of common sense; either alone should be sufficient.

Comment: @Bathsheba, What does UB mean? I am new here..

Comment: UB => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviours-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-a

Comment: @underscore_d Aaaawesome, Thanks!

Comment: Hi again guys, do you know why I got downvoted? I am new here and now it seems I cannot ask other questions because of the downvote. What should I do in this situation? Hope someone will see this comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What happens when we leave the scope knowing that the pointer is defined in the outer scope, a class member for example.

The pointer becomes a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

Dereferencing it to access the object's members, member variables as well as member functions, will lead to undefined behavior.